# grunt in watch mode and node.js lite-server

Tags: gruntjs, lite-server

Is there a way to start `node.js`'s `lite-server` from `grunt`?

I have `grunt` in watch mode and to use both at the same time I need to open two command prompt (windows). I'd prefer to start both with one grunt command - if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin `grunt-exec` does the trick with the command `npm run lite` (depending on `package.json` configuration).